# Matlab TCP-IP Server Lossless Transfer

Tags: matlab, tcp

I have tried and failed to implement a TCP-Listen server in Matlab that is "lossless".  By lossless, I mean using the linux socat utility to send a file:

```
socat -u file.bin TCP4:127.0.0.1:50000
```

And receive a byte-exact match to that file within Matlab:

```
function t = test
fid = fopen('x','W');
t =tcpip('0.0.0.0',50000,'NetWorkRole','server','InputBufferSize',50*1024^2);
t.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte';
t.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 1024^2;
t.BytesAvailableFcn = {@FCN, fid };
fopen(t);
function FCN( obj, event, fid )
x=fread( igetfield(obj, 'jobject'), obj.BytesAvailable, 0, 0);
fwrite( fid, x(1),'int8' );
```

I've tested this a good bit, and had decent success in terms of transfer rate (without the fwrite and use /dev/zero for the file, it saturates a gigabit link), and low cpu load.  The trick is bypassing Matlab's tcpip() default wrapper*, and accessing a lower-level method via:

```
igetfield(obj,'jobject')
```

For the 2139160576 Byte file I test with, it usually receives ~2139153336 bytes.  I've tried various other implementations that receive the fread() output into structs, cells, and array concatenation. They also are missing a few KiB's.  I've tried a repeating pattern of 512 random bytes; one test had byte mismatch at the beginning.

Socat->Socat transfer works (obviously).

Socat->my-matlab-code holds at fopen() until socat connects.  No data is transferred until fread() is called.  I've tried throttling the transfer with the linux "pv" utility:

```
pv -L 10m file.bin | socat -u - TCP4:127.0.0.1:50000
```

To no effect.

My question is: where are the bytes going, or what should I test next?

(Edited to include further test results):
Outputting to a file is unnecessary, i.e. the fwrite() call.  It is easier and faster to execute t=test, wait for the transfer to complete, i.e. the socat client to return, then query the total bytes transferred from within Matlab:

```
t.BytesAvailable + t.ValuesReceived
```

On my Windows machine, this value is always less than the file size of 2139160576 bytes.  On my Ubuntu machine, occasionally the values equate.  Furthermore, when they do not equate, "netstat -s" segments retransmited and packets discarded do not change.  Wireshark monitoring of the loopback interface shows a final Matlab/server ACK sequence number of 2139160578.  Presumably, 2 more than the file size due to both the server and client incrementing by one.

*As an aside, Matlab's Instrument Control Toolbox implementation of fread is a terrible wrapper around lower-level code I can't see.  matlab\toolbox\shared\instrument\@icinterface\fread.m, function localFormatData, LINE 296.  All the data types are explicitly cast to double with numeric type conversion.  This results in massive cpu load, not to mention lossy conversion between data types.

Comment: Could you explain that line: `fwrite( fid, x(1),'int8' );`? Why do you write only the first byte?

Comment: The 'jobect' fread method returns a java.lang.Object of size 3. Its first field?, i.e. x(1), is the read data.  Its second field is the size of the read data. Its third field is any messages.